# Put image in lower left corner of another image

Tags: php, image, gd

So, I've got this code that puts an image in the right lowermost point of an image.

Now I would like to do that exactly, but in the left lowermost corner. Just can't get the cords right. Any help?

```
<?php

    $main_img   = "image_path"; 
    $logoimage  = "logo_path"; 
    $padding    = 0; 
    $opacity    = 100;
    $logo       = imagecreatefromjpeg($logoimage);
    $image      = imagecreatefromjpeg($main_img);
    $logosize   = getimagesize($logoimage);
    $logowidth  = $logosize[0];  
    $logoheight = $logosize[1];  
    $image_size = getimagesize($main_img);  
    $dest_x     = $image_size[0] - $logowidth - $padding; 
    $dest_y     = $image_size[1] - $logoheight - $padding;
    imagecopymerge($image, $logo, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $logowidth, $logoheight, $opacity);

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$dest_x = $image_size[0] - $logowidth - $padding;
```

To this:

```
$dest_x = $padding;
```